# Are there any remains of ancient Dwarka city being found ever?

Tags: krishna

I have read that Dwarka, the city of Lord Krishna, emerged from sea and later again submerged into sea. So is there any investigation ever done to find the remains of the ancient city and is anything being found yet?

Also is there any mention of any of the residents who survived and shifted to any other place before it got submerged?

Answer (score 5):

Yes there are in the Bay of Cambay:

> According to marine scientists in India, archaeological remains of
>   this lost city have been discovered 36 metres (120 feet) underwater in
>   the Gulf of Cambay off the western coast of India. And carbon dating
>   says that they are 9,500 years old. It's speculated to be termed Dwarka, or the ‘Golden City.

Source ( [1](http://www.spiritofmaat.com/announce/oldcity.htm),[2](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/1768109.stm),[3](http://weburbanist.com/2007/09/12/underwater-urban-archeology-7-submerged-wonders-of-the-world/))

Comment: Well, a 9500-year-old city wouldn't be Krishna's Dwaraka; Krishna had the city of Dwaraka built after Jarasandha's invasion of Mathura.  And Krishna died 3102 BC, a little over 5000 years ago.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Kali Yuga starting during feb 18, 3102 BC (Krishna left to vaikunta) could be wrong. I think Mahabhartha happened still earlier. However, these carbon dating techniques never reconciled Hindu Astrological techniques.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Keshav is correct. Krishna left the earth in 3102 BC.

Comment: @Ajay Could be or could not be.